# Invoking stack command on specific stack.yaml file

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a multiple stack based yaml files for different resolvers in my Haskell project.

```
$ ls *yaml
stack.yaml
stack-lts-12.yaml
stack-lts-11.yaml
stack-lts-10.yaml
```

How can I invoke the `stack` build command for a specific yaml file ? By default, it picks up `stack.yaml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag `--stack-yaml file` works for me too. Not sure if it is available for all versions though. Tested with stack version 1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

To invoke the build process for a different stack yaml file, you need to set the `STACK_YAML` environment variable appropriately. Sample demo in bash:

```
$ STACK_YAML='stack-lts-12.yaml' stack build
...
...
```